# YouTube upload API Endpoint

Tags: api, video, upload, youtube, endpoint

For a while I've been hunting through the YouTube API but I'm a bit of a novice.

Is there anyway to provide an endpoint to, say, tweetbot that would allow video uploads to my youtube account? It's been only mind for a while now.

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score -1):

YouTube depreciated the ability to upload with V2 of their API

Comment: This does not provide a **solid** answer to the question, this should be a comment instead. You can always comment on your own posts, and once you have [sufficient reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). If you want to save your answer, update it with solid information and external references.